# Multiple Linux Grafana Integration

Tags: linux, grafana

I started with Grafana to monitor on-premise Linux Servers. I am using the Cloud Portal. On the Grafana Dashboard, I installed the Linux Server Integration using this tutorial -> https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/quickstart/agent_linuxnode/.

I used the command line on one server to setup the agent:

```
sudo ARCH=amd64 GCLOUD_STACK_ID="XXXXX" GCLOUD_API_KEY="xxxxx" GCLOUD_API_URL="https://integrations-api-eu-west.grafana.net" /bin/sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grafana/agent/release/production/grafanacloud-install.sh)"
sudo systemctl restart grafana-agent.service
```

It works perfectly with one server. However, when I added a new Remote Linux Server with the same command line, it replaced the previous server in the dashboard and I cannot select the other server. I feel I should not use the same command line, but I cannot find what parameters I should modify.

Did someone face the same issue and found a solution ?

Thank you in advance,
B.

**PS**: Ideally I would make it work using docker containers on each Linux Server, communicating to the Cloud Portal

Answer (score 0):

Assume `sudo systemctl restart grafana-agent.service` is restarting a specific server with the execution command in `/etc/systemd/system/grafana-agent.service`

If you want to have another `grafana-agent` you need additional service file. For example: `grafana-agent-2.service` with different configuration.